# Try fetch record from multiple entity

Tags: ios, core-data, entity

i will try to work with multiple entity with core data.
core data in two entity name is `Student` and `Detail` both have inverse relationship. relationship name is `Student -> Detail:detail` `Detail -> Student:student`. 
try to fetch record from both entity and display in table view. try multiple code but can't get result.

first code:

```
Detail *d;
NSMutableArray *arrObj = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(Student *tblObj in [d student]){
       [arrObj addObject:tblObj];
}
NSLog(@"Your records related with tableA = %@",arrObj);
```

can't load data in array.

second code:

```
NSArray* fetchResults = [_mainContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    for (int i; i > 1; i++) {
        Student *tableAObject = fetchResults[i];
        NSString * itemcode = tableAObject.detail.email;
        NSLog(@"%@",itemcode);
    }
```

can't display record.

third way:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *aEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Student" inManagedObjectContext:_mainContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:aEntity];

    NSString *relationshipKeyPath = @"detail"; // Set this to the name of the relationship on "SP" that points to the "Code" objects;
    NSArray *keyPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:relationshipKeyPath];
    [fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:keyPaths];

    NSMutableArray *arrObj = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for(Student *spObj in arrObj)
    {
        NSLog(@"description is %@",spObj.name);
        Detail *codObj = spObj.detail;
        NSLog(@"it has value %@",codObj);
        NSLog(@" unique name is %@",codObj.email);
    }
```

Code for insert data in core dta:

```
- (IBAction)submitData:(id)sender {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate manageObjectContext];

    Student *student = (Student *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Student" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    student.name = _nameText.text;
    student.number = _noText.text;
    student.study = _studyText.text;

    Detail *detail = (Detail *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Detail" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    detail.number = _noText.text;
    detail.email = _emailText.text;
    detail.address = _addressText.text;
    detail.contact = _contactText.text;

    student.detail = detail;
    detail.student = student;
    NSError *error = nil;
    [context save:&error];

    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"error in adding data %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
```

if you need more details let me know. Thank you.

Comment: show your code for inserting data into core data

Comment: check updated code @raki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two ways you have tried won't work as there is no code that related to fetch the data from core data. In the third way problem is you are not executing your fetch request.
Following is the way to fetch data from core data.

```
NSFetchRequest *req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Student"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *students = [context executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];

for (Student *stdObj in students)
{
    //Student object
    NSLog(@"Name %@",stdObj.name);
    NSLog(@"Number %@",stdObj.number);

    //Detail object related to student
    Detail *detailObj = stdObj.detail;
    NSLog(@"Email %@",detailObj.email);
    NSLog(@"Address %@",detailObj.address);
}
```

Comment: how can fetch both entity data using relationshipkey? single entity is work properly.

Comment: Thanks dude. can you other help for how to set fetchedResultControler in those data?

Comment: try to post another question by explaining your problem briefly and your tried code